# Based on dynamic JSON input request need to set the parameters value in POJO class

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I can pass any dynamic JSON as the request body from Postman. For Example-

JSON 1

```
{
      "controlNumber": "12345",
      "AssociateId": "1A23242aew",
      "EmployeeCode": "ABC"
}
```

JSON 2

```
{
      "controlNumber": "12345",
      "AssociateId": "1A23242aew",
}
```

JSON 3

```
{
   
      "EmployeeCode": "ABC"
}
```

Based on the input request, I want my specific POJO class properties to be set.
For example
if i pass JSON 2, then I want only two property `controlNumber` and `AssociateId` to be set in the POJO class, while other property should get some default or null values.

Below is the POJO class

```
public class EmployeeRequest{
    public String controlNumber;
    @JsonProperty("AssociateId") 
    public String associateId;
    @JsonProperty("EmployeeCode") 
    public String employeeCode;
}
```

**My try out**:
I created the `HashMap` out from the dynamic input request, and passing this `HashMap` as request to the all the downstream methods.

```
 HashMap<String, String> inputRequest_toMap = new HashMap<>();
        Field[] fields = employeeRequest().getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        String value = "";
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.get(employeeRequest().toString() != null)) {
                value = field.get(employeeRequest()).toString();
            }
            String key = field.toString();
            if (value != null) {
                inputRequest_toMap.put(key, value);
            }


        }
    }
```

PS: I want this result POJO class to be pass as parameter for the ibatis query.

Comment: You have to post a question to be able to answer it. What you have currently is a requirement. StackOverflow is not intended to convert requirements into code. You can try explaining what you have tried, and what specific problems are you having and then someone might be able to help you.

Comment: @OscarRyz I have edited the code and added what i have tried out which worked but not feasible solution for my project. can you please take a look now.

Answer (score 0):

More details might help the post, but if I'm understanding correctly some parameters might not be passed. This is not a problem.

If you use a website such as https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/json-to-pojo to create a base object with all parameters that could be sent, the unpassed parameters won't be defined after deserialization.

This could cause problems if you access these undefined members later, so you need some kind of indication of which members were passed (this could be a parameter that is always passed with your response, or an error-handling structure for when undefined members are accidentally accessed).